# Outputting a PHP variable inside a HTML image tag. Syntax problems

Tags: php, html, image, variables, tags

I'm storing image names in a database and I'm trying to work out who to output them in image form when I'm displaying the database contents.

Currently I'm doing

```
 echo $rank . " " . $row['name'] . " " . $row['points'];
```

The results of row name will be something like 243934.jpg and I want these to display as an image but I think I'm making mistakes in my syntax, I've tried:

```
echo $rank . "<img src="images/'.$row['name'].'"/>" . $row['points'];
```

But get a T_STRING error from SQL

Comment: Not from SQL that error is. And it's called PHP Syntax. And it's explained in the manual, maybe http://php.net/string but that depends a but, maybe just starting with first page: http://php.net/manual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not escaping correctly, this will work:

```
echo $rank . '<img src="images/' . $row['name'] . '" />' . $row['points'];
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by non-matching quotes in your `echo`. You need to use single quotes on the outside. Notice the coloring of the example in your question... the second `"` is ending the string - it needs to either be escaped or use a single quote.

```
echo $rank . '<img src="images/'.$row['name'].'"/>' . $row['points'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo $rank . '<img src="images/'.$row['name'].'"/>' . $row['points'];
```

Answer (score 0):

$row[ ' name '  ] is where you get the error, you should erase the quotes and leave it as $row[name].

Comment: This is incorrect as `$row[name]` would produce a `PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name'`. This error is because they are not escaping the `src` double quotes -`echo $rank . "<img src=\"images/{$row['name']}\"/>" . $row['points'];`

Comment: As @Sean pointed out, you'll probably want to re-think this answer... :)

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the `$row['name']` inside the double quotes for parsing, but you need to escape your `src` double quotes, and php array variables need to be encased in curly-brackets

```
echo $rank . "<img src=\"images/{$row['name']}\"/>" . $row['points'];
```

or

```
    echo $rank . "<img src=\"images/{$row['name']}\"/>{$row['points']}";
```